# Website on iOS Safari looks different in comparison with Desktop Safari; Chrome; Mozilla

Tags: ios, html, css, mobile, safari

im struggling with the display of a very simple website with inline css. Its by far not cutting edge, renders OK on Desktop, but as soon its viewed in Safari on iOS, text will be outside the container element and i have a empty space on the right side.

My goal is that its just adapting to the display resolution and allows a vertical scroll. I have tried so far several viewport combinations and css text wrap options ellipse etc. nothing changed... maybe im too stupid to see the mistake i made... heres the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>xx xxxxxxxxxxxxx</title>
<style>
    html { 
  background-color:#434c53;
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #777777;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #777777;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #0071CE;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0071CE;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_Calibri';
    src: url('fonts/Calibri.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/Calibri.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Calibri.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Calibri.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#Wrapper {
    max-width: 1280px;
    min-width: 960px;
    min-height: 960px;
    max-height: 1280;
    background-color: #E7E9EA;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0.93;
}

header {
    height:240px;
    background-color: #E7E9EA;
}

#MainNav {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:#E7E9EA;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-top: 36px;
    font-family:'Conv_Calibri',Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 100%;

}
#Content {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    padding: 80px;
    max-width: 1280px;
    min-width:960px;
    font-family:'Conv_Calibri',Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 160%;
}

#footer {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1280px;
    min-width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #E7E9EA;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-family:'Conv_Calibri',Sans-Serif;
    color:#777777;
    font-size: 100%;


}



</style>

</head>

<body>



<div id="Wrapper" >

    <header>
        <nav id="MainNav">
            <img src="dp_logo.svg" width="240" height="auto"
            </img>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="about_us.html">Über uns</a>
            <a href="solutions.html">Lösungen</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="Content" >

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>



</div>



</div>       
    <div id="footer">
        <section> 
    <p>

© xxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx  
</p>
        </section>

        <section>
            <p>
             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            </p>
        </section>

        <section>
            <p>
            <a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a>
            </p>
        </section>        

    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

what error did i make?

Comment: Your error is probably not using media-queries when targeting mobile and desktop at the same time!? And where are your tried viewports?

Comment: i deleted them after i noticed no difference. i used width=device-width.

Comment: Is media-queries the only way to solve this issue? Do you mean i should add all the available iOS resolutions / screen sizes to the css?